# Android-AVD :error loading preferences

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

i new to android programming and i am facing problem with AVD .when i launch avd couple of prompt come up and last one says error loading preferences .i am not able to figure out this problem .

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Emulator is very slow to start up. Even on faster computers. In my experience, it is quite normal to get the "error loading preferences".

Does the process of loading the emulator stop when you get that message, or does the emulator window pop up?

You could try to just let the emulator run for a bit longer, maybe 2-5 minutes and see if that helps. On my SSD only 8gb laptop, the emulator needs about 90 seconds to start.

Comment: a screen is there with android being written and blinking cursor

Comment: Could you just let it run for a couple of minutes (5-10) to  confirm that it isn't just slow?

Comment: Glad it worked! I am pretty new to stackoverflow, but I think it is good custom to mark a question as "answered" for further reference. Probably a good idea :-) Happy programming.

Answer (score 0):

Without specific error messages this is hard to work out. If you've exhausted your options with trying to dissect the problem, I would recommend a re-installation.

I have managed to get through the basics and have the emulator working. I will say though that it's not fool proof but it is quite stable.