# "Error loading preferences" in Intellij IDEA v.10.0

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I followed the "Hello World" Android tutorial in Intellij IDEA v.10.0. I created an AVD for Android 3.0, API Level 11.  I have Java SE Development Kit 6 Update 25 for x64 and the current Android SDK.   I ran the solution and got the error "Error loading preferences" in a window that quickly disappeared.  The emulater started ok but without my application or any of the emulator buttons.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend filing a bug to JetBrains YouTrack with idea.log attached.

Comment: I added my idea.log file to JetBrains YouTrack IDEA-68672, per your suggestion.

Comment: I added a link to my idea.log file here because I didn't get any responses on YouTrack. http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-68672?query=%23leehearn

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have two maybe unrelated problems:

The "Error loading preferences" almost all developers seem to get: see [Android-AVD :error loading preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5133803/818960)