# WinXP SP3 crashes running Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

Trying to run the Android Emulator on Windows XP SP3 the Emulator will start, it will get to the point where I can see the "ANDROID" text on the screen on the emulator, then a series of 3 windows command prompt windows will open, the final of which will say "Error Reading Properties" which is similar to the problem here [Android-AVD :error loading preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133803/android-avd-error-loading-preferences)

However after this dialog shows, XP crashes.

This was consistent across revision 10 and 13 of the emulator (I upgraded trying to get past the problem)

Has anybody had this problem? I haven't been able to reproduce it on any other machine than this one, I've done all the arbitrary updating of drivers etc. grasping at straws trying to make the emulator work...I can't think of what else to do

Forgot to add:

I've run the emulator with the -trace option, but all the files generated are empty.

Comment: What do you mean by "XP crashes"?  Are you getting a blue screen?  Some sort of crash dialog?  What is the error message?  Please be as specific as possible.

Comment: No BSOD, no error message, the screen goes black and the next thing I see is the BIOS screen =\

Comment: I've figured this out, it was a problem with my audio driver. I just disabled it and now the emulator is working perfectly...I'll give a fuller explanation when my 8 hours is up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a problem with my Audio driver. I had seen other people on forums reporting problems using LG headsets etc. and when they unplugged their microphones the emulator worked, but they were having different issues i.e. their system didn't reboot. I had also tried simply unplugging all my audio devices with no success. In the end I started in Windows Safe Mode, the Android emulator complained about no sound available, but didn't crash. So back in plain old Windows I just disabled my audio driver and it worked perfectly.